# how to update an object using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have userObject which has about 30 properties.

I get a updated userObject from the server and only sets the properties of the ones that have changed and returns the rest as null.

i am currently using a foreach and chk the value from the server is not null then update it. Is there a way to just to update the cells that are not null using linq?

linq to object

```
public class UserProfile
   {
        public string string00 { get; set; }
        public string string01 { get; set; }
        public string string02 { get; set; }
        public string string03 { get; set; }
        public string string04 { get; set; }

        public boolean bool00 { get; set; }
        public boolean bool01 { get; set; }
        public boolean bool02 { get; set; }
        public boolean bool03 { get; set; }
        public boolean bool04 { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: LINQ to what? LINQ to Objects? LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework?

Comment: Could you please post the code that you are using now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myClass currentObj = new myClass() { Text = "test", Value = 5 };
        myClass updatedObj = new myClass() { Text = "test 2 ", Value = 6 };
        Type cType = currentObj.GetType();
        var fieldInfos = cType.GetFields();

        foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
        {
            if (fieldInfo.GetValue(updatedObj) != null)
            {
                fieldInfo.SetValue(currentObj, fieldInfo.GetValue(updatedObj));
            }
        }
    }
}

class myClass
{
    public string Text;
    public int Value;
}
```

Just Template the code and change it into a function.
Some more info: [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-reflection-to-get-object-information)

Comment: thx..i already got it working with reflection but was wondering if it was possible to achieve the same thing using linq

Comment: I guess you could use LINQ on the reflection objects, instead of the foreach loop above, but that would be mighty weird.

Comment: i just figured it would be cleaner some how

Comment: well as @zmbq said it would be weird but something like this:
currentObj.GetType().GetFields().Select(x => { x.SetValue(currentObj, x.GetValue(updatedObj) != null ? x.GetValue(updatedObj) : x.GetValue(currentObj)); return x; }).ToList();

Comment: thats it...i guess it is weird but thats what i was looking for thx